# How to change a javascript alert box title into an UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I use an uiwebview into my iphone app.

When i display a javascript alert box, his title is my iphone app name.

How can i change it ?

Thank you,

Mo'

Comment: See also: [Change JavaScript alert dialog title in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681381/change-javascript-alert-dialog-title-in-ios)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the title of the `alert()` box from Javascript.

But you can [send a request to your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript) and display a UIAlertView from the app.