# How to unbold alert message?

Tags: javascript, ios, ios8, iphone-6

I added a custom alert in my web application based on the below suggestion for Alert issue. It works fine in iOS7 device, but on iOS8 device it displays the messages in bold font.

Is it possible to display the message font without BOLD?

Please find the attached screenshot for your reference.

[Change JavaScript alert dialog title in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681381/change-javascript-alert-dialog-title-in-ios)

Code snippet:

```
 function alert2(words){
        var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
        iframe.setAttribute("src", 'data:text/plain,');
        document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
        window.frames[0].window.alert(words);
        iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
      }

      function takePicture() {
          alert2("Testing custom alert");
       }
```

[image]

Comment: you're just calling `alert(...)`?

Comment: code snippet added. If I use just alert("Test"), then the header displays in bold and the message displays fine in iOS8.. I don't want header to be displayed on the screen

Comment: Marc B, any thoughts?

Comment: I'm guessing the alert overlay is part of the browser's built-in styles, and not something you can override at all. You could make your OWN popup purely with css overlays and whatnot, but it wouldn't have quite the same sideeffects as a normal alert() would.

Answer (score -2):

no you can't its OS or browser dependent but u can make your own pop up boxes which is also very easy