# send a notification from javascript in UIWebView to ObjectiveC

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios

I need to know what should be done to use JavaScript in a HTML sitting in `UIWebView` to notify Objective-C that something has happened?

To be more exact, I'm playing some JavaScript animation in HTML and I need to alert the Objective-C code that the animation has ended.

Comment: I just found an older question asking the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript. My answer below gives the same solution...

Comment: This is a clever hack, but a better technique can be found [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There seems to be no official method of doing this. However, [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript) [standard](http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2008/08/14/calling-objective-c-from-javascript-in-an-iphone-uiwebview/) [workaround](http://www.codingventures.com/2008/12/using-uiwebview-to-render-svg-files/) involves reading and parsing incoming URL requests, basically rolling your own serialized messaging protocol. The message handling should be done in the [`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:) method of your view controller.

*Note: there are several free libraries ([PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/), [QuickConnect](http://quickconnect.sourceforge.net/browser/index.html), [JS-to-Cocoa Bridge](http://code.google.com/p/jsbridge-to-cocoa/)) which wrap this functionality (plus do a whole lot more). To reinvent the wheel (or know why it's round, so to speak), read on.*

From JavaScript, you will invoke the callback by attempting to navigate to a new URL:

```
// In JavaScript
window.location = 'myapp:myaction:param1:param2'; // etc...
```

In Objective-C, implement the [`UIWebViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol in your `.h` file:

```
// In your header file
@interface MyAppViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
  ...
}
@end
```

Next, implement the method in your `.m` file:

```
// In your implementation file
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2
       shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
       navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  // Break apart request URL
  NSString *requestString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
  NSArray *components = [requestString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

  // Check for your protocol
  if ([components count] > 1 &&
      [(NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"myapp"])
  {
    // Look for specific actions
    if ([(NSString *)[components objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"myaction"])
    {
      // Your parameters can be found at
      //   [components objectAtIndex:n]
      // where 'n' is the ordinal position of the colon-delimited parameter
    }

    // Return 'NO' to prevent navigation
    return NO;
  }

  // Return 'YES', navigate to requested URL as normal
  return YES;
}
```

Two important notes:

1. **Context**: navigating to `myapp:whatever` will (of course) fail under any other context. Keep this in mind if you're loading cross-platform pages.
2. **Timing**: if a second `window.location =` call is made before the first returns, it will get 'lost.' So, either lump your calls together, manually delay execution, or implement a queue which combines the above with [JS queries into Objective-C objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html).

Comment: @dunforget, let me know how it goes. I got this part working in a test project, so let me know if you need any help. I'm testing out PhoneGap right now and am so-far impressed (easy to set up!)

Answer (score 3):

Actually for timing in iOS (maybe not for OSX?), if a second `window.location` call is made before the previous `window.location` call executes, then the first `window.location` call gets lost.  I think the `window.location` call executes asynchronisely with the JavaScript after it is called, and if another call is made it before it executes, it cancels the first.

For example, when capturing touch events, I have seen `ontouchstart` not get sent via `window.location`, if an `ontouchmove` event occurs to quickly afterwards (such as in a fast finger swipe).  Thus your Objective-C doesn't get the `ontouchstart` event.  This is more of a problem on the original iPad than the iPad2, I assume because of processing speed.

Answer (score 1):

zourtney's answer is correct , but forgot to mention one thing  .. needed to register delegate to webview by

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];  --- instantiate _webview next .. then 

    _webview.delegate = self;  //important .. needed to register webview to delegate
}
```

hope this helps .....

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Version**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var webviewInstance: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        webviewInstance.delegate = self
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        let requestString: String = (request.URL?.absoluteString)!
        var components: [AnyObject] = requestString.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
        // Check for your protocol
        if components.count > 1 && (String(components[0]) == "myapp") {
            // Look for specific actions
            if (String(components[1]) == "myaction") {
                // Your parameters can be found at
                //   [components objectAtIndex:n]
            }
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```