# How to access javascript function variable in UIWebview

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I want to print variable value of javascript function in xcode console.
This is the script

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
var abc =@"My Value";
      alert('Hello world');
}
</script>
```

With help of

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunction()"]];
```

I able to run function and alert of @"Hello world" is display.

My main concern is NSLog(@"abc Value %@",?);
How to access abc value ="My Value";

I am new in javascript and don't have much knowledge of basic of javascript.

waiting for replay'

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this -- alert(abc);

Comment: plese explain in detail ,where to call alert(abc);

Comment: instead of alert('Hello world'); change it to alert(abc);

Comment: And if you require this abc value to your objective c code then return  abc from javascript function. And in objective c, assign to some string variable.

Comment: thanks.it work.insted of alert(abc),I return value in js function and access it as NSLog(@"string %@",[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunction()"]);Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this url

[iphone app and uiwebview with javascript code can i access variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747558/iphone-app-and-uiwebview-with-javascript-code-can-i-access-variables)

Comment: Hi,I run above code in shouldStartLoadWithRequest but string is blank.does i have to change in javascript?

Comment: Hi i have run in webViewDidFinishLoad delegate but still string is blank. i run in all possible ways.what is wrong?

Comment: see this url for more info ....   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747558/iphone-app-and-uiwebview-with-javascript-code-can-i-access-variables