# How to detect if UIWebview is currently using the built-in media player?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a `UIWebView` on screen, which automatically redraws when the device is rotated. I don't want it to redraw if the user has invoked a video from the web before rotating because redrawing cancels the video playback (although audio continues).

None of the following helped:

- `UIWebView` is not hidden by `MPMoviePlayer` instance
- Media playback does not invoke `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillDisappear`, or `viewDidDisappear`.
- `self.view.window` doesn't change, doesn't get any new subviews
- `UIWebview` does not get any additional subviews
- the `UIWebView` does not get any new subviews or change any `isBlahBlah` properties
- `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` only has 1 window, and that window only has 1 view (my main view).
- I tried the notification center thing ([Notified when media player opens from UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404480/notified-when-media-player-opens-from-uiwebview)) and did not receive notifications.

For reference, the video path I am testing with is http://trailers.apple.com/movies/fox/prometheus/prometheus-tlr1_r320i.mov

So basically my app has no way to detect that a video is currently playing. It seems like I should be able to detect, but searching around I couldn't find one. I don't need to interfere with the playback - just knowing it is playing would be fine.

Comment: OK, finally geez I've wasted an entire day on this. I found this here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718606/mpmovieplayercontroller-fullscreen-movie-inside-a-uiwebview     Based on that my viewController can interrogate it's self.view.subviews and if it finds a rogue memberOfClass:[UIView class] it knows something is up. What I do now is self.view bringSubviewToFront:rogueView to keep it showing.  Note to UIWebView - hunting down the root view and jamming a new UIView in there is not cool! Maybe document that! Gah!

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview