# Calling Objective-C Code From Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Currently, I have some Javascript being executed in my Objective-C code, like so:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@""
"//...script is here..."
];
```

The aforementioned script contains some if statements, and depending on certain conditions, I'd like to call certain Objective-C functions (that are in this same file).

Is there a way of doing this?  I can't seem to find one.

Would greatly appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stevenpsmith.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/executing-javascript-from-objective-c-in-an-ios-app/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Objective-C from Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript)