# Obj C: Dismiss modal view after going to a webpage

Tags: objective-c, wifi, modalviewcontroller

I have a modal view controller which has only a Webview in it. In my application, I check for web connection first. If it is not available, I present this modal view controller to go to web authentication page which accepts Wifi credentials. Now, after successful Wifi log in, I want to dismiss the modal view. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1662762/244343) answer should have what you're looking for. Basically, implement `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and make javascript perform a redirect to something like "loginSuccessful". Your webView will pass this in as the `request` param of the above method, and detect this, then call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:]`.