# Better way of putting javascript into xcode project

Tags: javascript, xcode, uialertview

I have a javascript function that currently is inside a html file.. And in my xcode project I have a button linked to a UIWEBVIEW (linked to my local html file which has the javascript )..

The code inside my html file is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var now = new Date();
var day = now.getDate();

if (day % 2 == 0)
 alert("Today is Day 2");
else
    alert("Today is Day 1");

</script>
```

Currently, it's displaying what I want, but the only problem is the alert title is displaying day.html . Anyway I can use xcodes UIAlert function but with my javascript?

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: Please post your answer *as an answer* and if it solves your problem, accept *that* answer.  By placing the answer in the question, it will be likely construed as "not a real question" and could possibly be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the title inside the UIWebView, however you could do some nasty trickery like this [How to call Objective-C from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript) to accomplish what you want.