# Does Safari for iOS supports embedded objects?

Tags: iphone, html, safari

I'd like to access the keychain services from an html5 website. In order to do it I was thinking if it would be possible to write a custom object to be embedded in the page trough the object tag (something similar to an activex or java object) but I haven't found any reference on what kind of object does safara for ios supports.

Does anyone knows if something like that could be done? Does Safari for ios supports custom objects?

Thanks in advance,

Epc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have browser plugins on the embedded Safari (unless Jailbreaking). The only embedded content you can have is what the browser already supports natively.

What you can do is call [Objective-C from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript) and [vice versa](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW21). Keep the security implications in mind though.