# Where does the alertbox title come from in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, alert, title

I'm developing an iOS app consisting of HTML functionality within a UIWebView object.

The app contains a number of javascript alerts e.g. `alert("Here is a message.")` which display the message fine, but the title of the alert box is set to `MyAppName.app`.

I would prefer this was set to `My App Name` instead, but can't see where this is set, or what value I need to change.

Comment: Note that apple retains the right to deny any applications to the app store that may be only a website wrapper, happened to my company once.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to change the title with javascript, but you can display a normal UIAlertView from your app, you can find the answer here:

[javascript to objective c call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript)

Comment: Hi Oscar, thanks for your response, but my question is what determines the alert title rather than how I can change it.

Comment: @Loftx The title is your application bundleID in the plist file.

Comment: do you mean the "Bundle identifer"? This is set to "uk.co.organisation.my-app-name" and changing it doesn't affect the title displayed in the alert.

Comment: @Lotfx was referring to the bundle display name, listed on your info-plist file.

Comment: This does not seem to be the case either. I have tried altering the bundle display name, but this doesn't have any affect on the title.