# How to pass json from JavaScript to iPad native app?

Tags: javascript, ios, json, ipad

I have an iPad native application with webviews. How can I call a native function in the webview and pass some JSON data to it?

Comment: Do you want to call Obj-C from JS or the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use window.External.notify like this following blog mentions

http://www.stevesaxon.me/posts/2011/window-external-notify-in-ios-uiwebview/

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite similar question to this one:

[How to call Objective-C from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript)

The two more popular frameworks for doing this are JSBridge (pretty lightweight)

http://code.google.com/p/jsbridge-to-cocoa/

and to some extend PhoneGap as a much more complete solution

http://phonegap.com/
.

I used the first one for some project and I have been pretty happy with it - but maybe it requires some small adaptions because the SBJSON framework it relies on changed while JSBridge was not properly maintained in the meantime.