# Getting selected elements programmatically from uiwebview?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, uiwebview

Currently I am taking [this sample website](http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/business/management-dashboard/view/Default.asp) and showing in my webview. The webpage is displaying correctly.

Now I am trying to figure out which data is selected once the user has tapped on the uiwebview.

For this I am able to get the CGPoint for the tap by using `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

```
-(void)singleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:myWebView];

    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).toString()", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y];

    NSString * tagName = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];

    NSLog(@"Selected Name: %@",tagName); 

}

// In log it is displaying [object SVGPathElement]
```

I want to get the exact data once user selects the vertical bar in first graph 
(E.g. 1994/1995/1996).

How to do this?

Comment: Is the HTML page under your control?

Comment: No its not under my control.But still you can suggest your opnion :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify what is that is not working for you... anyway, a couple of suggestions:

1. try with the following js in your tap handler:

   ```
   NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).innerHTML", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y];
   ```
2. when creating your tap gesture handler, specify a delegate for it (it can be your controller):

   ```
   tap1.delegate = self;
   ```
3. in your controller (or web view delegate), define the following delegate method:

   ```
   - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:    (UIGestureRecognizer*)otherGestureRecognizer {
       return YES;
   }
   ```
4. if you are using iOS 5, have a look at [this article about a glitch in `elementFromPoint`](http://www.icab.de/blog/2011/10/17/elementfrompoint-under-ios-5/).

By doing like this, I am able to get the exact HTML value for the selected object.

Comment: Be warned this doesn't work well for Google images or other sites that display images in funny ways...

Answer (score 0):

If they're all independent DOM elements, you should be able to listen for touchstart events in JavaScript, and when you get the event object, it should have *[event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target)*, this will be the element the user clicked on. You can then capture the data you need in JS, and then send it back to Objective-c. The best way to get data from JS to native code is to use a [UIWebView delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript), this should hopefully do the trick for you!

Answer (score 0):

When user make a selection on the UIWebView, make an AJAX http request, that you can intercept in your UIWebViewDelegate implementing the

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

method.

Then you can accept the request loading, block it, analyze it, do whatever you like with it.