# Retrieving nearest to point word from UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have a problem making easy user interaction with content, displayed with `UIWebView`. I want to avoid any userInteraction with it, but make some actions programmatically. When user tapped on the some place of the `UIWebView` I want to find the nearest word. Furthermore I want to know its rect. Is there any js functions, which will help me?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940987/getting-selected-elements-programatically-from-uiwebview) The code that is quoted both in question and answers should be a good start.