# remove elementFromPoint() displaying HTML charactor

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

I need to select some text from UIWebView. I referred this answer [Getting selected elements programatically from uiwebview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940987/getting-selected-elements-programatically-from-uiwebview?rq=1) But when i use tap it selecting text. But it displays all the HTML charactor also `Selected Name: 1 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Name of instrument`

```
-(void)singleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
 {

     NSLog(@"single tap");

 CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:wbCont];

 //NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).toString()", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y];

     NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).innerHTML", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y];

 NSString * tagName = [wbCont stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];

 NSLog(@"Selected Name: %@",tagName);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got answer from `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` function. I used below below code. It's working fine.

```
tagName=[tagName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;" withString:@""];
```