# Has anyone idea what does mean "objc://" in url

Tags: javascript

Has anyone idea what does it mean:
    `objc://`
In this javascript sample code line:
    `var invokeString = "objc://planner/openPDF?" + encodeURIComponent(fileName);`

Comment: it seems to be some custom URL handler protocol which is handled by an external application installed on the users machine.

Comment: It could be objective-c !!! The user works for ios and/or in obj-c and  set his drive name to objc

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Objective-C is not an application, and it appears to open a PDF of some sort, so I doubt it.

Comment: [Looks similar to me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `objc://` is a custom scheme, as http. Amongst other things it can be used to open a application that's registered for this protocol on Mac/iOS (I'm not sure if this is supported on windows or not).

Let's say my ios-app "Planner" is registered to handle objc:// then when accessing this URL in the browser the app will open "Planner" app on my iPhone and pass the URL to the app in the same way http://www.google.com opens you Safari (Or you standard browser) app and passes google.com.

Another example is Apple using `itmss://` for links to thier iTunes Music Store. Clicking one of thoses links will open the Music Store in iTines.

Here's an article about [registering schemes on iOS](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/). And wiki about [URI schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)

**UPDATE**

As Sheikh Heera commented, it can also be used as a way to communicate between an UIWebView (running an HTML/JS page) in an objective-c application (iOS/Mac) and the native application.

Answer (score 2):

I've Googled it and found [Calling Objective-C Methods From JavaScript](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?105941-Calling-Objective-C-Methods-From-JavaScript), it says you can call Objective C methods by invoking URL with custom protocol like

```
document.location="mycustomprotocolname:functionName?param1=value1&param2=value2..."
```

So `objc://` looks like a custom protocol to call an  Objective-C Method here.

Comment: does that imply the function name in the OP's url is `planner/openPDF`?  sounds weird.