# How to Call Native Iphone/Android function from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone

I am using Web View both in Iphone and Android. In Android, I use [create a variable](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) to call native Andriod functions/methods. But I have not able to find something similar in Iphone. So, how to call a native Iphone function from JavaScript.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### iOS

In iOS you could use a custom url scheme by implementing `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`. If I would by example want to change the toolbar's tint color:

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString *scheme = [url scheme];

    if ([scheme isEqualToString:@"color"]) {
        self.toolbar.tintColor = [self colorWithHexString:url.host];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

### Javascript

In javascript you just change `window.location`, which will launch a *fire and forget*:

```
window.location = 'color://' + color;
```

Just chain your parameters like:

```
window.location = 'myscheme://param1/' + value1 + '/param2/' + value2;
```

Just make sure you use **encodeURIComponent** to encode your parameters (to create a valid url).

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1662762/1916258)

### Android

In Android you add a javascript interface:

```
    WebView webView = getWebView();
    webView.loadUrl("http://localhost:8080");
    // must be after loadUrl on lower apis
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new AndroidBridge(this), "AndroidBridge");
```

...

```
public class AndroidBridge {

    private MainActivity activity;

    public AndroidBridge(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void changeNavbarBackground(String color) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "changeNavbarBackground " + color);

        Field f = R.color.class.getField(color);
        final int col = (Integer) f.get(null);

        activity.changeNavbarBackground(col);
    }
}
```

### Javascript

In javascript you use the javascript interface:

```
if (window.AndroidBridge) {
            window.AndroidBridge.changeNavbarBackground(color);
}
```

Comment: But how can I call XXXX function in javscript?

Comment: By using window.location. It's in the answer, maybe a bit hidden.

Comment: Sorry I am new. Can you put a some detail in window.location where should I put, functionName, parameter1,parameter2, parameter3, ... and  how can I get the return value

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and patient. Lastly, it will be great for me(and for other users) if you put an IOS function with 1 or paramters as an example and then call this function from javscript similarly that you have  done with Andriod

Comment: Thanks, But I have questions. First, I wonder why only use URL shceme on iOS? Is this essential? There isn't another solution without URL scheme? Second, As far as I know, Android could use URL scheme. why don't use URL scheme on Android?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase analytics sample for webview will give more insights to implement this feature.
Please check on this [sample](https://github.com/firebase/analytics-webview)

For testing you can host the sample webpart on some server and load that url on webview.