# HTML 5 in IOS to design screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, html

Is it possible to mix HTML 5 in with my native app? I want one page to be made with Objective-c and the other with HTML 5. If so can someone direct in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I did it as a test a few weeks ago. On your storyboard, you just have to drag a `WebView` component on, and link it with your `ViewController.h` interface. Here is an example of a mixed storyboard. First the `UIToolbar` with the buttons was dragged on it, then the `WebView`:

[image]

When the view loaded (`viewDidLoad`) you need to initialize the WebView:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webView.delegate = self;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

You can communicate between the WebView and iOS. [I did an explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14182048/1916258).

Also if needed, you can setup an internal HTTP Server. I've used [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer), which is very easy to install with [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/). Just create a `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios
pod 'CocoaHTTPServer',  '~> 2.2.1'
```

and command `pod install` from the project directory.