# Can I open the native Android Share Dialogue when building app using WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, webview, share

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928821/can-we-invoke-smart-phones-native-share-functionality-with-jquery) tells me it can be done while [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106447/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-share-on-facebook-link-that-opens-the-native-face) says it's not possible at all.
Am I reading the links wrongly? What is the most effective way to have a share button on a webapp built by WebView?

Answer (score 2):

You can share using android default share bottom sheet.
use the following component.

```
if (navigator.share) {
    navigator.share({
    title: 'Web Fundamentals',
    text: 'Check out Web Fundamentals — it rocks!',
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/web',
})
    .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
    .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
}
```

This provides native sharing experience on Android devices while using web.
[image: Native android share]