# HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" conflict with window.location = url

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, redirect, uiwebview

I use following javascript to handle "page loaded" event in my UIWebView:

```
(function() {
if (typeof Browser == "undefined") {
    Browser = {};
}
var onWindowLoaded = function() {
    Browser.commands.sendCommand("page-loaded");
};

if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    onWindowLoaded();
}
else {
    window.addEventListener('loaded', function(event) {
                            onWindowLoaded();
                            });
}
})();
```

I load it with `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`

sendCommand function calls `window.location = url;` (url with specific scheme to gives me possibility of events handling)

So everithing is fine, except one page: [online.rsb.ru](http://online.rsb.ru)

`UIWebView` shows me blank page

I started to analyze that page with curl, and that what I've got:

get for url online.rsb.ru

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2013 08:34:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://online.rsb.ru//

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2013 08:34:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 125
Last-Modified: Tue, 29 Jun 2010 06:59:42 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: i=wkMdtFIyzhljiGI7BEXfAg==; expires=Sat, 13-Sep-14 08:34:33 GMT; domain=online.rsb.ru; path=/
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CUR ADM OUR NOR STA NID"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

<html>
<head>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=https://online.rsb.ru/hb/">
<title></title>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

get for url https://online.rsb.ru/hb/

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2013 08:36:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Wed, 11 Sep 2013 12:50:56 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 152
Set-Cookie: i=wkMdulIyzoJJM3O1BB1nAg==; expires=Sat, 13-Sep-14 08:36:18 GMT; domain=online.rsb.ru; path=/
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CUR ADM OUR NOR STA NID"

<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">

 window.location = "faces/system/login/rslogin.jsp?credit=false"

 </script>
 </head>
</html>
```

So, I've found that my javascript can conflict with next lines of code:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=https://online.rsb.ru/hb/">
```

or with

```
window.location = "faces/system/login/rslogin.jsp?credit=false"
```

(the problem depends on my javascript, if I remove call of `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` page loaded fine)

Could anybody gives me advice, how can I avoid that conflict?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved:

I have replaced execution of window.location = url; in my script
with following code

```
 function sendURLToUIWebView(url) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", url);
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    iframe = null;
 }
```

related posts:

[How to call Objective-C from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript)

http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/