# How to call Objective-C function from javascript in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode, highcharts

I am integrating highchart in iOS . In that I need to send value from javascript(html file) to `Objective-C` method. (i.e) if I zoom in the highchart in `UIWebView`, I need to send the zoom cordinates of X axis from `javascript` to `Objective-C` by calling an `Objective-C` method after the zooming is done by the user. Can any one help me in doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this code & refer this [tutorial how to use](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/calling-objective-c-function-from-javascript-in-ios-applications/):

```
function execute(url) 
{
  var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  iframe.setAttribute("src", url);
  document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
  iframe = null;
}
```

Get more solutions for this from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript)